# How to Store gps locations to the server in android when no internet connectivity

Tags: android, android-gps

Iam able to store the gps location to server succcessfully when there is internet connectivity. But when there is no internet connection, i want to store some where in mobile and later need to push to the server. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible you can use sqlite db or shared prefs to store the gps locations and then push it when internet becomes available

Answer (score 2):

What I consider about your questions is that Your data is saving when Internet is there and when you are offline then also U want to save GPS location and when Internet is available then it should be synced with server. okay ?

For this , You can create a SharedPreference which can maintain all LatLng after a short period. and also define a method which can search net connectivity. ASAP connection established, you can sync your local stored value with server and don't forget to clear SharedPreference Value when it successfully synced with your server..

**Next time Please share your code for better understanding..**
Happy Coding.

Comment: hi @shanmugam.. Please check this Link,, This will help you for better understanding about SyncAdapter.. 


http://www.coderzheaven.com/2015/07/04/sync-adapter-android-simple-example/

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that extends BroadcastReciever like this:

```
    public class CheckConnectivity extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

        boolean isConnected = arg1.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        if(isConnected){
              //Store your GPS Coordinates when no Connection
             Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connection Lost", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else{

        //send your GPS Coordinates to Server
        Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
       }
     }
```

and Also don't forget to add permission in your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```